# How can I take integral just knowing the functiong graph?

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-function

$f:[-2,4]\to[-1,2]$ is a bijective function.

[image: ![enter image description here]]

How can I calculate
$$\int_{-2}^{3}f(x)dx + \int_{-1}^{2}f^{-1}(x)dx$$
using the graph?

Comment: Hi, A solution to what ? can you develop your question and share what you've already found ?

Comment: I could just draw a line coinciding the f graph in starting and ending points. Then solve the question using that the function of that line. But I guess, It's not a true way for this question.

Comment: You said you want to find a solution for this, but what is 'this ?

Comment: I don't understand, taking integral.

Comment: You want to calculate the integral. You know that f is continous and bijective so

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate it.

Comment: You can use the geometric link between $f$ and its reciprocal (symmetry each others with $y=x$ axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y=f(x)$, let $x=f^{-1}(y)$, then we want to calculate
$$\int_{-2}^3 f(x)dx+\int_{f(-2)}^{f(3)} f^{-1}(y)dy$$
Suppose $x_0$ is where $f(x_0)=0$. Now 
$$\int_{-2}^3 f(x)dx+\int_{f(-2)}^{f(3)} f^{-1}(y)dy\\=\int_{-2}^{x_0}f(x)dx+\int_{x_0}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^3f(x)dx+\int_{-1}^{f(x_0)=0}f^{-1}(y)dy+\int_0^{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)dy+\int_{f(0)}^2f^{-1}(y)dy$$
Now we see that for example
$$\int_0^3f(x)dx+\int_{f(0)}^2f^{-1}(y)dy=\text{area of rectangle }[0,3]\times[0,2]=6$$
or $$\int_{x_0}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^{f(0)}f^{-1}(y)dy=\text{area of rectangle }[x_0,0]\times[0,f(0)]$$
and so on.